# What encoding looks exactly like ASCII but has NULL bytes before each byte?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have a string that looks and behaves as follows (Python code provided). WTF?! What encoding is it in?

```
s = u'\x00Q\x00u\x00i\x00c\x00k'
>>> print s
Quick
>>>
>>> s == 'Quick'
False
>>>
>>> import re
>>> re.search('Quick', s)
>>>
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(s)
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:69: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if aBuf[:3] == '\xEF\xBB\xBF':
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:72: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aBuf[:4] == '\xFF\xFE\x00\x00':
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:75: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aBuf[:4] == '\x00\x00\xFE\xFF':
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:78: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aBuf[:4] == '\xFE\xFF\x00\x00':
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:81: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aBuf[:4] == '\x00\x00\xFF\xFE':
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:84: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aBuf[:2] == '\xFF\xFE':
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/chardet/universaldetector.py:87: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  elif aBuf[:2] == '\xFE\xFF':
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
>>>
>>> chardet.detect(s)
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
>>>
```

Comment: Note that you're probably (from my understanding of it, at least) doing kinda weird things here: You're taking a bytestring in UTF-16 and converting it to Unicode which then has the Codepoints U+0000, U+0051, U+0000, U+0075, ... – Also `chardet` apparently searches only for U+FEFF at the start which fails here.

Comment: I get the u'\x00Q\x00u\x00i\x00c\x00k' by reading it from a file then decode it so I can use it. What do you mean by "converting it to Unicode"?

Comment: The `u` in front of the string.

Comment: The ''u'' comes from read(). I don't think it's about any conversion, but simply about read() returning unicode objects.

Comment: @ionit bizau: You need to get `bytes` not `str` from your file, then find out what encoding you need to use to decode the `bytes` ... if you interpose default encoding and decoding steps at best you are wasting CPU resources and at worst stuffing up your data. This time you got away lightly because your data appears to contain no codepoint after U+00FF and is encoded in UTF-16BE.

Comment: Oh, I see. How can I read the file then in order to get bytes?

Comment: `chardet.detect(repr(s))` and the warnings will be gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UTF-16 big endian

Comment: YES! Awesome, thanks a lot. Now I do *s.decode('utf-16-be')* to decode it and it's all fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have UTF-16BE without a BOM. As documented, chardet doesn't grok UTF-nnxE without a BOM.

```
>>> s = '\x00Q\x00u\x00i\x00c\x00k' #### Note: dropping the spurious `u` prefix
>>> s.decode('utf_16be')
u'Quick'
>>>
```

chardet is also not smart enough to raise a DontBeSilly exception if you feed it unicode :-)